# incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

Tags: c#

I m getting an error when i try to use this code in visual studio
can some one please help me out

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

namespace mywebsite
{
    public partial class myregistration : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(IsPostBack)
            {
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Registration1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                Conn.Open();
                string checkuser = " Select count(*) from [userdata] where UserName='" + TextBoxuname.Text + "' ";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, Conn);
                int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
                if (temp == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write(" User Already Exists ");
                }

                Conn.Close();



            }
        }



        protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Registration1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                Conn.Open();
                string insertQuery = "insert into userdata (UserName,Password,Email,select country) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@email ,@Country)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, Conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", TextBoxuname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxpass.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBoxemail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DropDownListselectcountry.SelectedItem.ToString());

                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("manager.aspx");
                Response.Write("Resgistration is Successfull");

                Conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write("Error:" + ex.ToString());
            }

                    }
    }
}
```

The error:

> Error:System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at mywebsite.myregistration.Button1_Click1(Object sender, EventArgs e) in `enter code here`C:\Users\Rahul\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Project1\mywebsite\mywebsite\myregistration.aspx.cs:line 50

it showing error at line 50 i.e. com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
if i m removing it from the code the records are not inserting into db so please suggest me what must be done to the code.

Comment: You should be using parameterized queries throughout your application (as you do in the second query), not constructing your query by concatting strings.

Comment: WHy are you selecting country in the second statement?

Comment: It's so easy to paramerterize your queries in c#, don't do this string concatenation crap (you're actually doing it in the second query)

Answer (score 4):

```
string insertQuery = "insert into userdata (UserName,Password,Email,select country) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@email ,@Country)";
```

I think you need to remove the word "select"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string checkuser = "Select count(*) from [userdata] where UserName='" + TextBoxuname.Text + "' ";
```

ie, remove the space before `select`

Also try this:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into userdata (UserName,Password,Email,select country) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@email ,@Country)";
```

**On a side note:**

Dont use string concatenation instead try with paramerterize query

Answer (score 1):

It is because `select` is a keyword and you have a space in your column name. Write this query instead:

```
string insertQuery = "insert into userdata (UserName,Password,Email, [select country]) values (@Uname ,@Password ,@email ,@Country)";
```

Comment: Glad it's OK. And don't forget to make the other query parameterized like this one :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use inline SQL like this. Bad practice and open to SQL injection.
See [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

You want to use 
[Parameterized Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521(v=vs.100).aspx)

Please use something like this

```
using (SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Registration1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    Conn.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = Conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select count(*) from [userdata] where UserName=@username";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(TextBoxuname.Text);
        int temp = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        if (temp.Equals(1))
        {
            Response.Write(" User Already Exists ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I downvoted it because it doesn't answer the question. This wasn't the problem OP was asking about, while it is true that they should parameterize the query. Besides, OP already knows how to parameterize queries as the second one was done properly and others had already commented on the need to do that. This answer is useless.